# C++ Serialization / Protobuf / Flatbuf / MYSQL_RES

Tags: c++, mysql, serialization, protocol-buffers, flatbuffers

I have 2 servers (One for Database Connections and one or more for client connections) running in a machine. The job of the database connections server is to fetch data from MySQL database and give this to the other servers on request.

Right now the data transfer (Between the 2 servers) happens via `Json` (`json_spirit`)(Don't know why I designed it this way.).

I am coming up to a stage where the data that is loaded from the MySQL DB is huge when the server starts up and every 1 minute. And 1000s of smaller queries in between.

I can see the impact `Json` is having since I have to Parse `MYSQL_RES` to `Json` and transmit from the DB Connection server to Client connection server and then parse the `Json` to a data set.
I am looking to serialize my data or do something other than parsing since the overhead is slowing down the client connection server since it is waiting on the response from DB Connection Server.

What would you suggest to serialize `MYSQL_RES` struct?
I have read about Protobuf, Flatbuffer and serialization. But simply cannot make a decision.

Comment: And why didn't you take a look at replication to reduce the load?

Comment: The issue is the time lost in Parsing result set to json to resultset. Not DB Load. DB Load is manageable with RO endpoints and replication.

Comment: replication would only transport the new and changed  data, without the heavy load of json. parser.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction then? Like an article or an example page?

Comment: I tried to push your question to dba, but not enough wanted to do that. So ask in https://dba.stackexchange.com  and don't forget to add also which version of Db you are using